# Echo DB columns randomly in a sequence

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create lines of text from every row in a database. I would like to have the sequence of the columns to be random for every row i display.

The normal echo would be:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

 echo "{$row['Color']} {$row['Size']} {$row['Category']} <br>";
}
```

How I turn this into a random order for every line? I tried with the rand, the `array_rand` and the shuffle, but none of them seem to output the right in combination with the while function.

Comment: you mean to say that each row will be echoed in a different sequence of fields? like 123|132|321|312 etc?

Comment: you can check @awerti's answer. I might solve your problem. if not then you post back the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
   shuffle($row);
   echo implode(' ', $row).'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i'm not sure i can get what you mean with what youv'e asked, can you please add some examples of what you're after.

Ideally an array with the info ( could be fake ) and an example of the output you want.  Doesnt have to be HTML, can simply be a comma seperated list.

Without that i'd be guessing.

Comment: I want the content of my columns to display in random order for each row in the table.

E.g. Database:

Column1,Column2,Column3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3


Displayed randomly as:

231
123
213
312
312
231


Hope this makes sense:-)